# Cannot create an order from the admin with 0 total

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, place-order

I need to place an order from the Magento admin with a total of 0 (I select the product, then I hit "Custom price" to put the price at 0. But Magento seeing the total is 0 does not show me the payment option, hence I cannot place the order as it tells me to chose a payment method.

This worked in the past as we use it regularly to send missing items of a customer's order, so we have a total of 0 (shipping 0 as well). But strangely it does not work anymore.

Any help please?
Thank you

Comment: At this moment, I activated the payment method "Payment with a null sub-total" (sorry if it's not exactly that title, my Magento is in french) and now I am able to place an order with a total of 0. But I am sure this method was not activated before, so help still needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go to

> System > Configuration > SALES > Payment Methods

Find section `Zero Subtotal Checkout` and enable this method.

Comment: Thank you @preecha.c
As mentioned in the reply to my post, I ended doing what you say, and it works, but I am sure this was not enabled before.